# Show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_n} = \frac{1}{\pi }{\operatorname{B}}\left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}} \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $a_1= 0,a_2=1$ and $a_n = \sqrt {\frac{{{a_{n - 1}} + {a_{n - 2}}}}{2} \cdot {a_{n - 1}}}$ for $n \geqslant 3$. Is it true that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_n} = \frac{1}{\pi}{\operatorname{B}}\left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}} \right)$, where $\operatorname{B}(x_1,x_2)$ is the Beta function?

Having experimented with Maple and wxMaxima, I think this statement should be provable(?). For example, $a_{20}=.7627597635$ while $\frac{1}{\pi }{\rm B}\left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}} \right)=.7627597633...$.

I was also wondering whether this sequence is convergent, and I think I can show that. In fact, the subsequence $\langle a_{2n+1} \mid n\in\mathbb{N} \rangle$ is increasing while $\langle a_{2n} \mid n\in\mathbb{N} \rangle$ is decreasing and both subsequences are bounded, so they converge. Moreover, their limits are the same, so $\langle a_{n} \mid n\in\mathbb{N} \rangle$ converges, and even rough estimates show that the limit lies in $(0.758,0.766)$. But to show that it is exactly $\frac{1}{\pi }{\rm B}\left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}} \right)$ is more difficult. Nonetheless, I will write down the proof of convergence. Perhaps, it may hint somehow to ${\operatorname{B}}\left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}} \right)$ expressed as an infinite sum or infinite product or whatever.

---

Let's start with the observation that for all $n$: $0\leq a_{n}\leq1$. This holds since given two values in the interval $[0,1]$, their average and product lie again in this interval. So in particular the sequence $\langle a_{n} \mid n\in\mathbb{N} \rangle$ is bounded. What’s more, the subsequence $\langle a_{2n+1} \mid n\in\mathbb{N} \rangle$ is increasing while $\langle a_{2n} \mid n\in\mathbb{N} \rangle$ is decreasing. We shall prove this by induction, making use of the well known inequality $\sqrt{x y}\leq{\frac{x+y}{2}}$. Hence we get $$\tag{1}a_{n-2}^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot a_{n-1}^{\frac{3}{4}}\leq a_{n}\leq\frac{a_{n-2}}{4}+\frac{3a_{n-1}}{4}$$

Now we can prove that for all $n$ we have

$$\tag{2}a_{1}\lt \cdots\lt a_{2n-1}$$

$$\tag{3}a_{2}\gt \cdot\cdot\cdot\gt a_{2n}$$

$$\tag{4}a_{2n-1}\lt a_{2n}$$

For $n=1$ we see that (2) and (3) are vacuously true and (4) is obvious. And for the induction step we have to show $$\tag{5}a_{2n-1}\lt a_{2n+1}\lt a_{2n+2}\lt a_{2n}$$

We start by observing that $$\tag{6}a_{2n+1}\lt a_{2n}$$

since by definition $\displaystyle a_{2n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}}{2}\cdot a_{2n}}$ and from (4) it follows that $\displaystyle{\frac{a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}}{2}}\,\lt \,a_{2n}$.

Now for the first inequality of (5), note that by the first inequality of (1) we have $a_{2n+1}^{4}\ge a_{2n-1}\cdot a_{2n}^{3}$, and by (6) this is greater than $a_{2n-1}\cdot a_{2n+1}^{3}$, so $a_{2n+1}\gt a_{2n-1}$ as required. Similarly, $a_{2n+2}^{4}\geq a_{2n}\cdot a_{2n+1}^{3}\gt a_{2n+1}^{4}$, which proves the second inequality of (5). For the last inequality of (5) we use the second inequality of (1), so $\displaystyle a_{2n+2}\,\leq\,\frac{a_{2n}+3a_{3n+1}}{4\,a n+1}\,\lt \,a_{2n}$ (by (6)). That completes the induction proof.

---

Now we can easily prove that both subsequences converge to the same limit. This is because by (1) $\displaystyle a_{2n+2}-a_{2n+1}\leq{\frac{a_{2n}-a_{2n+1}}{4}}$ and by (5) this last difference is less than $\displaystyle\frac{a_{2n}-a_{2n-1}}{4}$. So the distance between $a_{2n+2}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ is less than a quarter of the distance between $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-1}$, and therefore these distances go to zero. That implies both subsequences have the same limit.

Regarding the value $l$ of the limit, if - inspired by (1) - we define the sequence $\langle b_{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle $ by $\displaystyle b_{n}={\frac{b_{n-2}}{4}}+{\frac{3b_{n-1}}{4}}$ and $b_1=0,b_2=1$, then clearly $a_{n}\leq b_{n}$. Also, it is not hard to prove that $\displaystyle b_{n}=\frac{4}{5}\left(1-\left(-{\frac{1}{4}}\right)^{n-1}\right)$, which converges to $0.8$. In the same way, if we define $c_{n}=c_{n-2}^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot c_{n-1}^{\frac{3}{4}}$, then we better ignore the initial value $0$, so we just put $c_{2}=1,c_{3}=a_{3}={\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}$ and when we switch to $d_{n}:=\log_{2}c_{n}$, then $d_{2}=0,d_{3}=-{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $d_n$ satisfies the same recurrence relation as $b_n$. Therefore, for $n≥2$, $\displaystyle d_{n}=\frac{2}{5}\left(-1+\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-2}\right)$, which converges to $-\frac{2}{5}$, so $c_n$ converges to $2^{-{\frac{2}{5}}}$, which is approximately $0.758$.

In fact, returning to $b_n$, but using initial values $b_{2}=1,b_{3}=a_{3}={\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}$, we can show $b_n$ converges to $\displaystyle\frac{1+2{\sqrt{2}}}{5}$, which is approximately $0.766$.

Comment: Your constant is just $\frac 1{\text L_1}$ with the [first lemniscate constant in formula $(7)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LemniscateConstant.html)

Comment: This reminds me of the [Arithmetic–geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic–geometric_mean)

Comment: So it seems that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \frac 2 \pi M(1, \sqrt 2)$ where $M(x, y)$ is the Arithmetic–geometric mean (which is defined by a similar recursion). I wonder if there is a transformation between the two recursions.

Comment: Setting $b_n=1/a_{n+1}$ we can see that $b_1=1,b_2=\sqrt{2}$ and $$b_{n+2}=\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{b_n+b_{n+1}}{2b_n}}}$$ which means that if $c_n=b_{n+1}/b_n$ then we have $$c_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+c_n}}$$ Perhaps this can help to get some information on $c_n$ and then we can express limit of $b_n$ as an infinite product.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: The recursion $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{\frac{1+x_n}{2}}$ has well-known explicit solutions (using the half-angle formulas for cos or cosh). But I don't know if that can be used here.

Comment: @MartinR: unfortunately I have not been able to link the recurrence for $c_n$ in my comment with the typical formulas related to elliptic integrals and their friends (elliptic, theta functions etc). My best guess is that the relation to elliptic stuff is indirect or involves some other ideas.

Comment: @MartinR: finally someone managed to give meaning to the recursion we discussed.

Comment: Aaron Levin deals with this problem with more details in their paper [A Geometric Interpretation of an Infinite Product for the Lemniscate Constant](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F27641976).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First note that, if $a_0=0,a_1=1$ and $a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}\left(\frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}\right)}$, we can define $(x_n)_{n\geq0}$ as $x_n=\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ with initial value $x_0=0$ and the recursion formula
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+2}}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{\sqrt{a_{n+1}\left(\frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}\right)}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+x_n}}$$
So $a_n=\prod\limits_{k=1}^nx_k^{-1}$ and $a_\infty:=\lim_n a_n=\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty x_k^{-1}$. Now consider the Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp_1(z):=\wp(z,1,0)$ satisfying $\wp_1'(z)^2=4\wp_1(z)^3-\wp_1(z)$ and define
$$\mathfrak{P}(z):=\frac{\wp_1(z)^2+\frac{1}{4}}{\wp_1(z)^2-\frac{1}{4}}\ \text{ with }\ \mathfrak{P}(0)=\lim_{z\to0}\mathfrak{P}(z)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1+\frac{1}{4}\wp_1(z)^{-2}}{1-\frac{1}{4}\wp_1(z)^{-2}}=1$$

$\color{#FF5200}{\bf{Lemma\ 1.}}$ The function $\mathfrak{P}$ satisfies the two following identities $$\mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z}{1+i}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\mathfrak{P}(z)}},\quad \mathfrak{P}\left((1+i)z\right)=\frac{2}{\mathfrak{P}(z)^2}-1$$

*Proof.* First notice that $\wp_1(iz)=\wp(iz,1,0)=-\wp(z,1,-0)=-\wp_1(z)$ and so $\wp_1'(iz)=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dz}\left[\wp_1(iz)\right]=i\wp_1'(z)$. By the addition formula of Weierstrass elliptic functions,
$$\wp_1((1+i)z) = \frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{\wp_1'(z)-\wp_1(iz)}{\wp_1(z)-\wp_1(iz)}\right]^2-\wp_1(z)-\wp_1(iz)$$
$$= \frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{\wp_1'(z)-i\wp_1(z)}{\wp_1(z)+\wp_1(z)}\right]^2-\wp_1(z)+\wp_1(z)=\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{(1-i)\wp_1'(z)}{2\wp_1(z)}\right]^2=\frac{1}{8i}\frac{\wp_1'(z)^2}{\wp_1(z)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{8i}\frac{4\wp_1(z)^3-\wp_1(z)}{\wp_1(z)^2}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\wp_1(z)-\frac{1}{4}\wp_1(z)^{-1}\right)$$
Now we can prove the second expression as
$$\mathfrak{P}\left((1+i)z\right)=\frac{\wp_1((1+i)z)^2+\frac{1}{4}}{\wp_1((1+i)z)^2-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\frac{-1}{4}\left(\wp_1(z)^2-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16}\wp_1(z)^{-2}\right)+\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{-1}{4}\left(\wp_1(z)^2-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16}\wp_1(z)^{-2}\right)-\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$\frac{\wp_1(z)^2-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16}\wp_1(z)^{-2}-1}{\wp_1(z)^2-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16}\wp_1(z)^{-2}+1}=\frac{\wp_1(z)^2-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{16}\wp_1(z)^{-2}}{\wp_1(z)^2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16}\wp_1(z)^{-2}}$$
$$=2\frac{\wp_1(z)^2-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16}\wp_1(z)^{-2}}{\wp_1(z)^2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16}\wp_1(z)^{-2}}-1=2\left(\frac{\wp_1(z)-\frac{1}{4}\wp_1(z)^{-1}}{\wp_1(z)+\frac{1}{4}\wp_1(z)^{-1}}\right)^2-1 = \frac{2}{\mathfrak{P}(z)^2}-1$$
and the first one follows from the second. $\square$

The former expression is crucial as, if we find $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathfrak{P}(z_0)=0$, it let's us express $$\forall k\in\mathbb{N}:x_k=\mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z_0}{(1+i)^k}\right)\Rightarrow a_\infty=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z_0}{(1+i)^k}\right)^{-1}$$
so our main goal is to obtain the root $z_0$ and, then, compute the infinite product.

$\color{#FF5200}{\bf{Lemma\ 2.}}$ The equation $\mathfrak{P}(z_0)=0$ has the solution $z_0=\frac{(-1)^{-3/4}}{4}B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)$

*Proof.* Consider $\mathfrak{P}(z_0)=0$. First note that, differentiating,
$$\mathfrak{P}'(z)=-\frac{\wp_1(z)\wp_1'(z)}{\left(\wp_1(z)^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}=-\frac{\wp_1(z)\sqrt{4\wp_1(z)\left(\wp_1^2(z)-\frac{1}{4}\right)}}{\left(\wp_1(z)^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}$$
$$ = -\frac{2\wp_1(z)^{3/2}}{\left(\wp_1(z)^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3/2}}=-2\left(\frac{\wp_1(z)^2}{\left(\wp_1(z)-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}\right)^{3/4}$$
$$=-2\left(\frac{\left(\wp_1(z)+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{\left(\wp_1(z)-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}-1\right)^{3/4}=-2(\mathfrak{P}(z)^2-1)^{3/4}$$
And, as $\mathfrak{P}(0)=1$ and $\mathfrak{P}(z_0)=0$, we have
$$z_0=z_0-0=\mathfrak{P}^{-1}(0)-\mathfrak{P}^{-1}(1)=-\int_0^1(\mathfrak{P}^{-1})'(t)dt=-\int_0^1\frac{1}{\mathfrak{P}'(\mathfrak{P}^{-1}(t))}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^{3/4}}dt=\frac{(-1)^{-3/4}}{2}\int_0^1(1-t^2)^{-3/4}dt$$
and, substituting $t=\sqrt{s}\Rightarrow dt=\frac{1}{2}s^{-1/2}ds$, we finally see that
$$z_0=\frac{(-1)^{-3/4}}{2}\int_0^1(1-s)^{-3/4}\frac{1}{2}s^{-1/2}ds=\frac{(-1)^{-3/4}}{4}B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)\ \square$$

$\color{#FF5200}{\bf{Lemma\ 3.}}$ The following infinite product holds
$$\mathfrak{P}'(z)=2z^3\prod_{k=1}^\infty\mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^k}\right)^{-3}$$

*Proof.* First observe that, via recursion, we have
$$\mathfrak{P}'(z)=\frac{d}{dz}\left[\mathfrak{P}(z)\right]=\frac{d}{dz}\left[\frac{2}{\mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z}{1+i}\right)^2}-1\right]=-4\frac{\mathfrak{P}'\left(\frac{z}{1+i}\right)}{1+i}\left(\mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z}{1+i}\right)^{-3}\right)$$
$$=(-4)^n\frac{\mathfrak{P}'\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^n}\right)}{(1+i)^n}\prod_{k=1}^n \mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^k}\right)^{-3} =(1+i)^{3n}\mathfrak{P}'\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^n}\right)\prod_{k=1}^n \mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^k}\right)^{-3}$$
where we have used Lemma 1 and the fact that $-4=(1+i)^4$. Now, it is not hard to prove that $\mathfrak{P}(z)=1+\frac{1}{2}z^4+...$ so $\mathfrak{P}'(z)=2z^3+...$ and
$$\lim_n(1+i)^{3n}\mathfrak{P}'\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^n}\right)=2z^3\lim_n\frac{\mathfrak{P}'\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^n}\right)}{2\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^n}\right)^3}=2z^3\lim_{s\to0}\frac{\mathfrak{P}'(s)}{2s^3}=2z^3$$
Hence, taking $n\to+\infty$, we finally obtain
$$\mathfrak{P}'(z)=\lim_n\left[(1+i)^{3n}\mathfrak{P}'\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^n}\right)\right]\prod_{k=1}^\infty\mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^k}\right)^{-3}=2z^3\prod_{k=1}^\infty\mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z}{(1+i)^k}\right)^{-3}\ \square$$

$\color{#FC3503}{\bf{Theorem.}}$ We can express the limit $a_\infty=\lim_na_n$ as
$$a_\infty=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{(-1)^{-3/4}B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)}{4(1+i)^{k+1}}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\pi}B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\right)$$

*Proof.* Isolating the infinite product from the previous expression, we see
$$a_\infty=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\mathfrak{P}\left(\frac{z_0}{(1+i)^{k+1}}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{z_0}\sqrt[3]{\frac{\mathfrak{P}'(z_0)}{2}}=-\frac{4(-1)^{3/4}}{B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)}\sqrt[3]{(\mathfrak{P}(z_0)^2-1)^{3/4}}$$
$$=-\frac{4(-1)^{3/4}}{B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)}\sqrt[3]{(-1)^{3/4}}=-\frac{4(-1)^{3/4}(-1)^{1/4}}{B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)}=\frac{4}{B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$
where $z_0=\frac{(-1)^{-3/4}}{4}B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\right)$. So, using the value $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$, we conclude that
$$a_\infty=\frac{4\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}=\frac{1}{\pi}B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\right)\ \square$$

Comment: Beautiful solution! Minor point: What do you mean by $(-1)^{-3/4}$?

Comment: I must say that this link with elliptic functions is totally non-obvious. +1 for the great and detailed solution.

Comment: Can you please shed some light on the genesis of the functions involved ie the Weierstrass elliptic function with invariants $g_2=1,g_3=0$? The ratio $(\wp(z) ^2+1/4)/(\wp(z)^2-1/4)$ is even more mysterious.

Comment: @Gary: my guess is that we can give meaning to that expression by noting $-1=\exp(i\pi)$ so that $(-1)^{-3/4}=\exp(-3i\pi/4)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, I was wondering if the branch of fourth root matters.